# How to programmatically create MS Office .doc or .docx files on a linux server

Tags: linux, ms-office, openoffice.org

In the past I've used [catdoc](http://www.wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/) for reading .doc files, but now I need to write them.

What is the best way to go about this? I don't need it to be perfect or fully featured.

Comment: Both libroffice and openoffice have some API to do this (e.g. in Python). But I don't know the details.

Comment: I believe unoconv is the widely-used utility that uses LibreOffice. http://linux.die.net/man/1/unoconv

Comment: If you know C, you can use libopc.  If you know Java, you can use docx4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a quick and dirty way would be, to write your file in HTML and save the file as .doc
Because word can open HTML you would have a Word File^^
Beware that if you open the file with word sometimes the "web-view-mode" is selected

Comment: Seriously? Interesting... Do you have a source for that by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: source not directly but i used it several times, in my case i created a word document as a template, saved it as HTML, did some edits in the document via standard File IO and resaved it as .doc, there are some stumblingblocks, like changing headers and footers, but it works^^

Comment: Also I'm assuming using images isn't feasible. Anyways, testing this now. Quick & dirty is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: i tryed it, actualliy it even works with pictures, as long as they are available via internet or on your local drive.

Comment: Great solution. This is simple and quick. A more refined solution, I've learned, is unoconv. Although it is too involved for my current purposes, I should mention it here for future googlers. http://linux.die.net/man/1/unoconv